# get IIS server configuration host settings using PHP

Tags: php, iis

I've a web application running on IIS over SSL. I need to read out or check the value 'UploadReadAheadSize' from ApplicationHost.config from the site I use.

Is it possible to get the value using PHP?

I like to popup a message in the frontend if the value is limited to 49152 (which is default) and let the user know how to increase it to one or two MB.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't like C# has Microsoft.Web.Administration and c++ has ahaadmin. Microsoft haven't release offical API assembly for PHP to manage IIS configuration.

So I think you could get that configuration by running powershell commandline in PHP

```
Get-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST'  -filter "system.webServer/serverRuntime" -name "uploadReadAheadSize.Value"
```

Comment: Nice idea. Had a similar one using appcmd.exe. Both won't work without elevated admin rights.